# How to programatically start/stop message consumption when using @MessageMapping annotation?

Tags: spring, messaging, spring-cloud, spring-messaging

Am using the `@MessageMapping(queue_name)` annotation along with the spring-aws-cloud library to consume messages from two SQS queues.

I see that the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` is used as the listener container for both message queues. There is a `start()` and a `stop()` method on the container, but I believe that will start/stop consumption from both queues.

I wanted to know if there is a way to programatically start/stop queue consumption for the queues separately. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Use `start(queueName)` and `stop(queueName)` function of `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` to start and stop individual queues programmatically.

Comment: These do work, but do you have any idea thy they take ~20 sec to complete, I had to increase the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You need separate containers for each queue to start/stop listening independently.

From a quick look at the code, it appears to me that there is only one listener container when using the annotation to create listeners.

I suggestion you open an issue/feature suggestion in [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues); I suggest you post the issue number back here so interested parties can follow the discussion.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Created issue in GitHub
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/67